# SQL query "DESCRIBE EMPLOYEE;" equivalent in Neo4j Cypher. (How to see data types of Properties of a Label ?)

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-cql

Is there any equivalent for SQL "DESCRIBE EMPLOYEE;" in Neo4j Cypher. How to see data types of Properties of a Label ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j does not have a fixed schema for node properties and types. There is nothing preventing you from using differing types for values of the same property on different nodes.

That said, you can get something similar by using [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/). [apoc.meta.data](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_meta_graph) takes a sample of data in your graph and gives you info similar to what you're seeking, just YIELD the fields you want, and filter based upon the label you're interested in.